# Magento 2 Pricing Terminology Documentation

Tags: magento2, price

I am currently looking at the sales_order_item table which mentions the following fields:

**base_cost

price

base_price

original_price

base_original_price

tax_amount

base_tax_amount

tax_invoiced

base_tax_invoiced

discount_percent

discount_amount**

As this is being used for real transactions any clear documentation on the criteria for these fields is critical. Do you know where it can be found officially, not as footnotes on QA websites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what `base_cost` does, but here is what the others mean.

- price - the price for which the product was bought in the currency that the order was placed
- base_price - same as price but in the base currency of the store
- original_price - original price of the product being bought in the currency that the order was placed (may be different from price if there is a discount applied)
- base_original_price - same as original_price but in store default currency
- tax_amount - the total amount of taxes applied to the product being bought in the currency in which the order was placed. The value may depend on how many taxes you have configured and on the ax settings you have (included in the price added in the backend or excluded)
- base_tax_amount - same as tax_amount but in the default currency of the store
- tax_invoiced - the total amount of taxes that were invoiced in the currency that the order was placed. In magento you can partially invoice an order or fully invoice it. When you partially invoice it you can have partial tax invoices.
- base_tax_invoiced - same as tax_invoiced but in the store base currency
- discount_percent - discount percentage applied to the order item
- discount_amount - discount amount applied to the order item.

Comment: Do you have any sources?

Comment: nope. Just digging around for the past years.